# Can you emulate the shift key being held before the event runs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want the user to be able to scroll left and right by scrolling normally which can be achieved by scrolling with the shift key held. is there a way to run the event with the "shiftKey" variable set to true even when it is not held down?

Comment: Why not overriding the scroll event and programmatically scrolling the page horizontally?

Comment: Because the native scrolling is much smoother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to capture scroll event as wheel event, because scroll event will not work without the actual scrollbar and apply scroll data to the scroll left position.

```
var variation = 0;
    document.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
    variation += parseInt(e.deltaY);
    console.log(variation);
      //document.getElementById("body");
      document.documentElement.scrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft = (variation);
    return false;

}, true);
```

Try this jsfiddle link which I have created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zc2e1L7/)

Comment: This works, but especially with images being scrolled, there is a big difference in smoothness in contrast to the native scrolling with shift pressed. Yes, you can set the scroll type to smooth, but this is still not the same, especially when scrolling fast unfortunately...